# How can I customize the spaces between consecutive equations in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, equations

I am working on my thesis (a `report` type file) in which I have several consecutive equations associated to some mathematical model. The thing is that those are too separate to each other and looks not pretty good, so I would like to know how can customize this. I am using a `report` type file and I have been around though to many pages without finding a good answer to this.

The code is the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k \in K} \sum_{i \in V_{1}}v_{ijkg} \leq d_{jg} \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in V_{1}}\sum_{j \in V_{2}} \sum_{g \in G} v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}} \sum_{k \in K} v_{ijkg} \leq W_{ig}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d_{jg}y_{jk} \geq v_{ijkg}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \ast z_{i}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_{ijkg} \leq Q_{k} \ast F_{ik}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{g \in G}v_{ijkg} \leq M \ast \sum_{s \in V} x_{sjk}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V,s \neq h} x_{shk} - \sum_{s \in V,s \neq h} x_{hsk}=0,\hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall h \in V, \hspace{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{jkg}-u_{lkg}+Q_{k}x_{jlk} \leq Q_{k}-\sum_{i \in V_{1}}v_{ijkg}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j,l \in V_{2},j \neq l, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}}x_{ijk} + \sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{jik} \leq 2,\hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in V_{1}} \sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} \leq 1, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V,s \neq j}x_{sjk}=y_{jk}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k \in K}F_{ik} \leq I \ast z_{i}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} = F_{ik}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V} \sum_{p \in V} T^{c}_{sp} x_{spk} \leq SRT, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K_{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{s \in V} \sum_{p \in V} T^{h}_{sp} x_{spk} \leq SRT, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K_{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_{spk} \in \{0,1\} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall s,p \in V,s \neq p, & \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K \hspace*{0.2 cm} \\ y_{ik} \in  \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k  \in K & \\ v_{ijkg}  \in \mathbb{Z}^{+0}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall & k \in K,  \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall  g \in G \\ z_{i} \in \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm}  \forall i \in V_{1}&  \\ F_{ik} \in \{0,1\}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall  & ,k   \in K \\ u_{jkg} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} j \in V_{2} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k  \in  & K, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall g  \in G
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Here is a picture of some part of the output. The equations list take two entirely sheets.
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have somewhere in your document `\usepackage{setspace}` followed by `\doublespacing` or something, correct?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you use the `gather` environment? That would save quite some typing, and I think the spacing would be better.

Comment: I have \usepackage{setspace}, but not \doublespacing

Comment: never start a paragraph with display math or use consecutive display math enviornments. As you see, the spacing will be completely wrong. Use a multi-line display such as `align` (if you need alignment) or `gather` (if you do not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the `align` environment instead of multiple `equation` environments?

You can align multiple equality symbols with that. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
asdasd asdasd

\begin{align}
\sum_{k \in K} \sum_{i \in V_{1}}v_{ijkg} &\leq d_{jg} \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace{0.1 cm} \forall g \in G \\
\sum_{i \in V_{1}} \sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} &\leq 1, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall k \in K
\sum_{s \in V,s \neq j}x_{sjk}=y_{jk}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall j \in V_{2}, \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K \\
\sum_{k \in K}F_{ik} &\leq I \ast z_{i}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1}
\sum_{j \in V_{2}} x_{ijk} = F_{ik}, \hspace*{0.3 cm} \forall i \in V_{1} \hspace*{0.1 cm} \forall k \in K \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I hope this helps.